# How to support Drop-in directoris for JavaFx FXML and Controllers?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx-8, fxml

I'm currently working on a menuing system for which loads its menu options from FXML files, where each FXML files references its own controller. These menu options are not particularly complex, but I need to support the capability for the menuing system to automatically detect new menu options that may have been installed.

My first thought it to support a drop-in directory, which holds each menu options jar files, where the jar files would contain the fxml, controller, model, and any other resources the menu options uses. However, I'm running into an issue where I cannot view the contents of a folder inside the jar file the way I normally would, as I need the resource path in order to load the resource. Since I do not know the contents of the jar ahead of time, I cannot load the specific .fxml by its resource path.

Is there a way to support this feature? Even a way to list the contents of a folder inside a jar wold be helpful.